# OpenGL Alpha Channel not affective

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, alpha

Trying to make objects that fade over time in openGL.

I am doing this by decreasing the value of the Alpha in the color I am using to draw the object. But this does not seem to have any effect on the object, it still draws it as solid.

I have simplified the code to simply drawing three rectangles. Each rectangle is drawn with the same color but a different alpha value.

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void display(void)
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    // Set the color to red, with alpha at 100%
    float   f1[] = {1.0, 0, 0, 1.0};
    glColor4fv(f1);
    glRecti(10, 10, 110, 110);

    // Set the color to red, with alpha at 50%
    float   f2[] = {1.0, 0, 0, 0.5};
    glColor4fv(f2);
    glRecti(120, 10, 220, 110);

    // Set the color to red, with alpha at 20%
    float   f3[] = {1.0, 0, 0, 0.2};
    glColor4fv(f3);
    glRecti(230, 10, 330, 110);

    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);␣
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 5000.0);
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0);
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch (key) {
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_ALPHA);

    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 1200);
    int id = glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    // Set up call back
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    glutDestroyWindow(id);
}
```

The code that does the display is all in `display()`. I have included all the other functions openGL functions I use as I am probably not setting something up correctly.

Comment: If this is the full program, then you forgot to enable blending with `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`.

Comment: Tried adding `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` to main() => crash. To reshape() and  display() nothing changed.

Comment: Read about [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) -> `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` `glEnable(GL_BLEND);`. Of course you must add this code after `glutCreateWindow`

Comment: Is this your full program? The program never clears the buffer, thus accumulating colors over multiple frames. Since the buffer is also not cleared at the start, the initial color/alpha value is probably (0,0,0,0). Blending anything with a full transparent background will probably not give the result you expect. You also need to set the blend func (`glBlendFunc`).

Comment: @Rabbid76 That worked. I added those two function directly after the glutCreateWinow()` and it now works as expected. Thanks. If you put that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @BDL I simplified my application to show the problem. Actually trying to create fireworks that fade out over time. Are you saying the default for clearing the screen should be: `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 255);glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable blending and set an appropriate blend function (see [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)). To run an OpenGL instruction, you need an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). The context is create when the OpenGL window is created with `glutCreateWindow`. Therefore you must add the instructions after `glutCreateWindow`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_ALPHA);

    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 1200);
    int id = glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);


    //
    // After the window has been created set the window
    // To enable the alpha part of the color.
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    // DONE    



    // Set up call back
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    glutDestroyWindow(id);
}
```